# how can i make like this background with shadow?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains an image and overlay:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <img src="tablet.png" alt="tablet">
</div>
```

How can I make an overlay with shadow like [image: this]?

Comment: show your complete code so that we can understand where you are going wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried so far ? Where's your code ?

Comment: i just wanna do like that shadow in the image in link !

Comment: i just wanna do like that shadow in the image in link !

Answer (score 1):

While it surely can be done via CSS or SVG, most likely that shadow is just a background image where the shadow is already drawn.

However, here's an example of how you could think of it in css:

```css
.scene {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #60c18b;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.object {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: url(https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.onlinewebfonts.com%2Fsvg%2Fimg_121330.png&f=1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: top left;
}

.object:after, .object:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), transparent);
  transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: absolute;
}

.object:before {
  transform: translateY(2px) skew(0deg, -45deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
   background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.3), transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="object"></div>
</div>
```

Note that this is just for fun, it's not perfect and I wouldn't use this on a production site.